# Advertisements in blackberry app

Tags: blackberry

In my blackberry application,i am displaying advertisements in screen.But only 2 ads were displaying in a screen at a time.Is there any other option to display more ads?

Please help.

I am working on both OS6 and OS7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, create a seperate Object for your Banners.

> The Advertising Service API can support up to two active Banner
>   objects on a screen at one time (only one for BlackBerry 6).
>
> If your application displays more than one ad (even if on different
>   screens), you should create a separate Banner object for each ad
>   placement.
>
> Reusing a Banner object in multiple locations, might cause ads to
>   display incorrectly.
>
> You shouldn't attempt to remove a Banner object from a screen without
>   removing the containing field manager as well, as this can lead to
>   issues with other Banner objects.
>
> Using a FlowFieldManager object to display Banner objects might cause
>   ads to display incorrectly.

(Taken from the official Blackberry Page)

Link: [BB APP ADVERTISEMENT](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/40306/Creating_a_BB_app_that_displays_an_ad_1176551_11.jsp)